# Linq Where Clause Change based on Parameters

Tags: linq, where-clause, switching, clause

I have a linq statement that returns a list of records based on where clause 
This where clause checks for two parameter values.

Out of which one parameter is optional.
so i need a suggestions if i can switch my where clause based  on the optional Parameter
something like this

```
if(locid==0)
  {
   where (p.CustomerID == custid)
  }
 else{
   where (p.CustomerID == custid) & (p.LocationID == locid )
     }
```

can any one help me how can i get this work.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try writing it like this:

```
where (p.CustomerID == custid) && (locid == 0 || p.LocationID == locid )
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes - queries can be composed (although you don't need this for this particular case as @rsbarro pointed out):

```
var query = p;

if(locid==0)
   query = query.Where( p =>p.CustomerID == custid);
else
   query = query.Where( p =>p.CustomerID == custid & p.LocationID == locid);

//any other conditions
```

Answer (score 1):

As BrokenGlass mentioned, you should use composition:

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = unfiltered.Where(p => p.CustomerID == custId);
if (locid != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.LocationID == locid);
}
```

Note that the query is *not* executed until you start reading data from it, so you needn't worry about this making multiple requests.

It looks like in your original post you were trying to use query syntax piecemeal - that won't work, but the "dot notation" is pretty simple here. You can always create your initial query using a query expression if you want - again, that query won't be executed immediately anyway.